# How to delete entries when a specific object property does not exists in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

For example, in the following PSCustomObject, I wish to remove the objects for which TagName does not exist

```
$dataset1 = @(
    @{
        MachineName = "AAA"
        ID   = "111"
        TagName = "GroupA"
    },
    @{
        MachineName = "BBB"
        ID   = "222"
        TagName = "GroupB"
    },
    @{
        MachineName = "CCC"
        ID   = "111"
        TagName = ""
    },
    @{
        MachineName = "DDD"
        ID   = "333"
        TagName = ""
    },
    @{
        MachineName = "EEE"
        ID   = "111"
        TagName = ""
    }
    }
```

So, after deletion the $dataset1 should contain the following:

```
$dataset1 = @(
    @{
        MachineName = "AAA"
        ID   = "111"
        TagName = "GroupA"
    },
    @{
        MachineName = "BBB"
        ID   = "222"
        TagName = "GroupB"
    }
   }
```

Comment: Why just `$dataset1 | where {$_.TagName -ne "" }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Where-Object`(or alias name `where`). [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-7.2#description) returns all objects for which the script block statement is true

```
$dataset1 = $dataset1 | Where-Object { $_.TagName }
```